# Can I use Ember-CLI tests for a globals-based Ember app?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-testing

We have an Ember app that does not use Ember-CLI. The guide says to use Ember-CLI for testing.

Can we write unit tests for parts of our application using Ember-CLI? Does this require moving to ES6 modules or can we use globals based source code for testing?

Comment: what guide? can you provide an example test of what you don't know if it works so we know what you are looking at?

Comment: what build tooling does your global(s) based ember app use today? You could update to a ES6 like structure w/out going full ember-cli and testing would certainly be improved/easier. Here is a full gulp based example that has the nice(r) testing w/ non globals (just as a reference). https://github.com/toranb/ember-gulp-example